# "undefined reference" to static member of template class accessed from static method

Tags: c++, templates, static

I have a static class method that needs access to a pointer MyTypePointer that therefore has to be declared static. Since it is a template class I have to put the methods inside the header file but I can't define MyTypePointer in the header.

So I get the **"undefined Reference"** error since MyTypePointer is not declared. How can I make this work / declare MyTypePointer.

```
myclass.h

template <typename A, typename B>
class PathfindingClass {
    typedef std::vector<GenericEdgeClass<A, B>*> MyType;
    static MyType *MyTypePointer;
};

template <typename A, B>
void MyClass<A, B>::MyMethod(int x, int y) { 
    //do something with MyTypePointer
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You'll need to put a **definition** for it along the template declaration (in the header).

Comment: Actually, your problem is "*defining*" the static member, not declaring it. And I think you'll have to do it for every instantiation of your class template explicitly in a CPP file yourself. I'm probably wrong though!

Comment: @yzt No, it should be defined in the header. The linker will care for multiple instantiations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Oh, thanks! Damn, all this time I've been second-guessing the linker and making this particular problem for myself!

Answer (score 15):

It is a late answer for full reference, as this question is linked as a reference to another question.

A minimal broken example of a static field *declared* but not *defined* could be :

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    static T val;
    static void init()
    {
        val=0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // A::init();
    A<double>::init();
    return 0;
}
```

The fix is just to define the static field after the class definition :

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    static T val;
    static void init()
    {
        val=0;
    }
};

template<typename T> T A<T>::val; // only change here

int main()
{
    // A::init();
    A<double>::init();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another way in C++17 is to mark the variable as `inline`, then you don't need to define it again outside the class.

Answer (score 6):

In the template definition, `static MyType *MyTypePointer;` **declares** an object. You still have to **define** it, outside the template class definition:

```
template <class A, class B>
typename PathfindingClass<A, B>::MyType*
PathfindingClass<A, B>::MyTypePointer;
```

Comment: Doesn't this lead to multiple instances of `MyTypePointer` if several source files include this header and instantiate this template with the same `A` and `B`?

Comment: Works! Thank you!
I'll spend the evening trying to get my head around what's actually happening there.

Comment: @yzt - no. Just like with template functions, the implementation is responsible for sorting out duplicates and ending up with only one copy.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Oh, thanks! Damn, all this time I've been second-guessing the linker and making this particular problem for myself!

Comment: Interesting! I'm pretty sure that this didn't work in C++03 but I can see in 14 [temp] paragraph 6 that clearly `static` members need to be defined in all translation units cause implicit instantiation...

Comment: @DietmarKühl At least GCC (w.o. std specification) supported this behavior since a number of recent versions (at least I know GCC 4.6 does for sure). But I've seen crappy (just put syntactic sugar upon c) compilers, that don't behave well with this, but these usually have some more problems with their template implementations.

Answer (score 3):

You can still define the template member and explicitly instantiate it for all needed specializations. If you insist in having a `state` data member of a class template that's roughly what's needed.

Given that global variables share all sorts of problems, including dependency issues during initialization, you are much better off, wrapping you data member by a `static` member function:

```
template <typenane T>
class foo {
    // ...
    static X*& member() {
        static X* rc = ...;
        return rc;
    }
};
```

The local variable is initialized the first time the function is called and a reference to it can safely be used. This approach also works for templates.

Note that I still recommend to avoid global variables! They cause many problems in the long-term and short-term benefit of using them is a huge debt which normally doesn't pay off.

Comment: Thanks. I'm avoiding global variables for that very reason. Also I guess, using global variables when templates are involved is probably not so easy in the first place?

_I realize this is probably not the right place but can you recommend a book (de, eng, fr, it) that explains the more complicated aspects of cpp?_

Comment: @user3049681: Well, the canonical book for C++ is "Effective C++" by Scott Meyers. Beyond that, there are several books for various aspects but I'm not aware of any one book. With respect to template "[C++ Templates](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Templates-The-Complete-Guide/dp/0201734842)" seems the most complete book but it doesn't cover the changes introduced with C++11 (i.e., it should be considered "the incomplete guide" until gets updated).