# Linker Error in template specialization of a class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, linker-errors

- I have a header file TimeSeries.h, which has definitions and specializations of default_value template
- TimeSeries class has other methods
- I included TimeSeries.h file in main.cpp

### This is my header file TimeSeries.h, followed by main.cpp

```
    template<typename>
            struct default_value;    
            template<>
            struct default_value<int> {
               static constexpr int value = 0;
            };

            template<>
            struct default_value<double> {
               static constexpr double value = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
            };

            template <typename T>
            class TimeSeries
            {
            public:
               std::vector<uint64_t> timeUsSinceMid;
               std::vector<T> values;

               void addValue(uint64_t time, T value)
                {
                 timeUsSinceMid.push_back(time);
                 values.push_back(value);
                }

               TimeSeries<T> * sample(uint64_t sampleFreq, uint64_t startTime=0, uint64_t 
                 endTime=86400*1000*1000ULL)
                {
                 //Some code
                 // I essentially faked a time and a default value push
                  TimeSeries<T>* newSample = new TimeSeries<T>;
                  newSample->timeUsSinceMid.push_back(timeUsSinceMid[0]);
                  newSample->values.push_back(default_value<T>::value);
                  return newSample;
                }
            };
```

Here is main.cpp:

```
#include<TimeSeries.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    TimeSeries<double> T;
    T.addValue(1, 100.0);
    T.addValue(2,200.0);
    T.addValue(3,300.0);
    T.addValue(4,400.0);
    TimeSeries<double>* newT = T.sample(2,1,6);
    //cout<<*newT<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

### This is the linker error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "default_value<double>::value", referenced from:
      TimeSeries<double>::sample(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone please explain why "default_value::value" is undefined?

Comment: Can you split the main and header please?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok! I will define the other required methods here and separate the header and main.

Comment: `push_back` use reference, you odr-use those `static const`. Thus definition needed.

Comment: I didn't understand @li

Comment: @n.m The code should now be complete and verifiable. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642103/undefined-reference-to-static-member-of-template-class-accessed-from-static-me).

## Using the structure of your posted code

Your template definition *defines* the object `value`, but it still needs to be `declared`.
Don't ask me why, I'm just copying @Pete Becker's answer from the other post (which unfortunately wasn't very detailed). All I know is that the below code now compiles:

```
template<>
struct default_value<double> {
    static constexpr double value = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
};
// EDIT: inserted line below
constexpr double default_value<double>::value;
```

## Changing the structure a bit

Alternatively, if you don't want to have to track value declarations through a large project, you can also turn the `value`s into in-lined methods, like so: (**edit** added in `constexpr`'s; also noting that `inline` is not required & likely doesn't change compiler behavior)

```
template<>
struct default_value<int> {
    // EDIT: changed value to function
    static inline constexpr int value() {
        return 0;
    }
};

template<>
struct default_value<double> {
    // EDIT: changed value to function
    static inline constexpr double value() {
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    }
};
```

Of course, remember to change your `TimeSeries::sample` method to use `default_value<>::value` as a method.

Comment: It works. This is really strange. I am aware that a static member should be defined outside the class, after it's declaration, but not the other way around. I will read more about it and post whatever I find. Thanks @Shillard.