# C-style wrapper to C++ functor

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

This is further developing on what I was trying at [this recent question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78022704).

I want to create a `bool(double, double)` C-style function pointer to a functor with compatible signature. (The reason for the further attempt is that the earlier approach seemed to have restrictions on what can be `constexpr`-ed.)

How can I do in C++ the equivalent of the following working Python code:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class FixPrecCompare:
    '''Compares two floats to the given precision'''
    def __init__(self, numDigits: int) -> None:
        self.factor = 10 ** numDigits
    def __call__(self, a: float, b: float) -> bool:
        return int(a * self.factor) == int(b * self.factor)
    
class AreClose:
    '''Same as Python's inbuilt math.isclose [which should be called areclose :-)]'''
    def __init__(self, absTol = 0, relTol = 1e-09) -> None:
        self.absTol = absTol; self.relTol = relTol
    def __call__(self, a: float, b: float) -> bool:
        diff = abs(a - b)
        return diff <= self.absTol or \
            diff <= abs(self.relTol * a) or \
            diff <= abs(self.relTol * b)

# Now for signature compatibility (which is not a matter in Python)
# I make a function which internally uses the functor
def makeApproxCompare(FunctorType: type, *args):
    functor = FunctorType(*args)
    def fn(a: float, b: float) -> bool:
        return functor(a, b)
    return fn

approxCompare2 = makeApproxCompare(FixPrecCompare, 2)
approxCompare3 = makeApproxCompare(FixPrecCompare, 3)
areClose = makeApproxCompare(AreClose, 1e-3)

a, b = 4.561, 4.569
print(f"Compare {a:.3f}, {b:.3f} to 2 decimals: {approxCompare2(a, b)}")
print(f"Compare {a:.3f}, {b:.3f} to 3 decimals: {approxCompare3(a, b)}")

a, b = 2.7099, 2.7101
print(f"Compare {a} to {b} to 3 decimals: {approxCompare3(a, b)}")
print(f"Compare {a} to {b} using areClose: {areClose(a, b)}")
```

My attempt:

```cpp
typedef bool(*SuccessTester)(double, double);

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct FixPrecCompare
{
    FixPrecCompare(int numDigits): factor(pow(10, numDigits)) {}
    bool operator()(double a, double b) { return int(a * factor) == int(b * factor); }
private:
    double factor;
};

struct AreClose
{
    AreClose(double absTol, double relTol): abs_tol{absTol}, rel_tol{relTol} {}
    bool operator()(double a, double b)
    {
        double diff = fabs(a - b);
        return diff <= abs_tol ||
            diff <= fabs(rel_tol * a) ||
            diff <= fabs(rel_tol * b);
    }
private:
    double abs_tol, rel_tol;
};

template<typename Functor>
struct Helper
{
    static Functor fr;
    static bool func(double a, double b) { return fr(a, b); }
};

template<typename Functor, typename ... ArgTypes>
SuccessTester makeSuccessTester(ArgTypes ... args)
{
    Helper<Functor> h;
    h.fr = Functor{args ...};
    return &h.func;
}

int main()
{
    SuccessTester fp;
    cout << boolalpha;

    double a, b;
    
    a = 4.561; b = 4.569;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare>(2);
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 2 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare>(3);
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 3 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    
    a = 2.7099; b = 2.7101;
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 3 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<AreClose>(1e-3, 1e-10);
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " using areClose: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
}
```

But on GCC this gives:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEkJxbk.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN6HelperI14FixPrecCompareE2frE' in read-only section `.text._ZN6HelperI14FixPrecCompareE4funcEdd[_ZN6HelperI14FixPrecCompareE4funcEdd]'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEkJxbk.o: in function `bool (*makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare, int>(int))(double, double)':
<src>:(.text._Z17makeSuccessTesterI14FixPrecCompareJiEEPFbddEDpT0_[_Z17makeSuccessTesterI14FixPrecCompareJiEEPFbddEDpT0_]+0x38): undefined reference to `Helper<FixPrecCompare>::fr'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEkJxbk.o: in function `bool (*makeSuccessTester<AreClose, double, double>(double, double))(double, double)':
<src>:(.text._Z17makeSuccessTesterI8AreCloseJddEEPFbddEDpT0_[_Z17makeSuccessTesterI8AreCloseJddEEPFbddEDpT0_]+0x4e): undefined reference to `Helper<AreClose>::fr'
/usr/bin/ld: <src>:(.text._Z17makeSuccessTesterI8AreCloseJddEEPFbddEDpT0_[_Z17makeSuccessTesterI8AreCloseJddEEPFbddEDpT0_]+0x55): undefined reference to `Helper<AreClose>::fr'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEkJxbk.o: in function `Helper<FixPrecCompare>::func(double, double)':
<src>:(.text._ZN6HelperI14FixPrecCompareE4funcEdd[_ZN6HelperI14FixPrecCompareE4funcEdd]+0x2b): undefined reference to `Helper<FixPrecCompare>::fr'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEkJxbk.o: in function `Helper<AreClose>::func(double, double)':
<src>:(.text._ZN6HelperI8AreCloseE4funcEdd[_ZN6HelperI8AreCloseE4funcEdd]+0x2b): undefined reference to `Helper<AreClose>::fr'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And Clang is somewhat better:

```
<src>:40:7: warning: instantiation of variable 'Helper<FixPrecCompare>::fr' required here, but no definition is available [-Wundefined-var-template]
    h.fr = Functor{args ...};
      ^
<src>:52:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare, int>' requested here
    fp = makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare>(2);
        ^
<src>:32:20: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
    static Functor fr;
                  ^
<src>:40:7: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'Helper<FixPrecCompare>::fr' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit
    h.fr = Functor{args ...};
      ^
<src>:40:7: warning: instantiation of variable 'Helper<AreClose>::fr' required here, but no definition is available [-Wundefined-var-template]
    h.fr = Functor{args ...};
      ^
<src>:59:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'makeSuccessTester<AreClose, double, double>' requested here
    fp = makeSuccessTester<AreClose>(1e-3, 1e-10);
        ^
<src>:32:20: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
    static Functor fr;
                  ^
<src>:40:7: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'Helper<AreClose>::fr' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit
    h.fr = Functor{args ...};
      ^
2 warnings generated.
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/<src>-ce7af1.o: in function `bool (*makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare, int>(int))(double, double)':
<src>:(.text._Z17makeSuccessTesterI14FixPrecCompareJiEEPFbddEDpT0_[_Z17makeSuccessTesterI14FixPrecCompareJiEEPFbddEDpT0_]+0x1a): undefined reference to `Helper<FixPrecCompare>::fr'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/<src>-ce7af1.o: in function `bool (*makeSuccessTester<AreClose, double, double>(double, double))(double, double)':
<src>:(.text._Z17makeSuccessTesterI8AreCloseJddEEPFbddEDpT0_[_Z17makeSuccessTesterI8AreCloseJddEEPFbddEDpT0_]+0x28): undefined reference to `Helper<AreClose>::fr'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/<src>-ce7af1.o: in function `Helper<FixPrecCompare>::func(double, double)':
<src>:(.text._ZN6HelperI14FixPrecCompareE4funcEdd[_ZN6HelperI14FixPrecCompareE4funcEdd]+0x1f): undefined reference to `Helper<FixPrecCompare>::fr'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/<src>-ce7af1.o: in function `Helper<AreClose>::func(double, double)':
<src>:(.text._ZN6HelperI8AreCloseE4funcEdd[_ZN6HelperI8AreCloseE4funcEdd]+0x1f): undefined reference to `Helper<AreClose>::fr'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I'm not sure how to fix the code to make it work as desired. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: `return &h.func;` you are returning a pointer to a local object, that's not going to work even if you get it to compile.

Comment: I suspect the fundamental problem here is that C++ doesn't create garbage collected closures in the way that python does. If you are prepared to use `std::function<bool(double,double)>` instead of a function pointer it will be easier.

Comment: This approach isn't going to work unless you can guarantee exactly one instance of any Functor type is in use at any given time. You need to wrap the Functor in a state parameter, and add that as an extra parameter.

Comment: The core problem is C pointers are not closures, and you can't make them that on there own. You need to handle the state manually.

Comment: Related to one of your issues: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20642103 (In C++17 this can also be solved with `inline static Functor fr;`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/c3hWs9q6r What doing it with a state parameter would look like with C style state parameters. This example does not free the state parameter which you would have to do. I did it C style, as I assume the primary reason for doing this is to pass this through a C api.

Comment: Are macros an option on the table?

Comment: @alagner Could be. How could that help?

Comment: I've asked, becasue if so, you can wrap non-capturing lambda in a macro and then freely convert it to function pointer, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3c1zaK5q7). This is not necessarily optimal, but might be enough for your needs.

Comment: @john I made that `h` static.

Comment: @user1937198 Excellent point about guaranteeing once instance of Functor type. Basically I found that after I instantiate makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare, int> once the further instantiations don't happen at all. Will look into your state example.

Comment: @alagner Wow that seems very simple and doesn't even need the Helper type. This might just solve my problem! But why do you call it not necessarily optimal?

Comment: @alagner But what is that + before [] for?

Comment: @alagner Is it not fully optimal because it keeps initializing the Functor object every time it runs? That can be fixed by making `static auto fr` no? Or would that still initialize it every time it runs?

Comment: + acts as a cast to function pointer. Yes, static could help here, but keep in mind it might involve mutex locking upon first run. Also, macros do not convey type-safety.

Comment: @alagner Thanks for your response but I was looking at [CppRef: Lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and it does not seem to mention anything about `+`?

Comment: It's not mandatory for your case, it should convert automagically when initializing variable of type `SuccessTester`. However, using the + forces the conversion to function pointer enabling the usage of auto and protecting from capturing anything in such situation by giving a more local error message, uncomment the asserts [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hEbvaj15r).

Comment: I guess it's not mentioned in the docs as it's probably assumed to be covered by automatic type conversions: unary+ is the operator of a function pointer, which the lambda is implicitly converted to; using it forces the conversion instead of relying on operator overloading later. It's the same trick like `char x='a'; cout << +x;` to print char's decimal value instead of `cout << static_cast<int>(x);`. Consider it as a shorthand for `static_cast<SuccessTester>([](double, double){//whaterver});` which is generally equivalent. Any of those should do, but I strongly recommend one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

The principal problem with your approach is that you are trying to assign several different values to the same static member at once. `Helper<FixPrecCompare>::fr` is a unique variable, because you declared it static, and it can't hold both `FixPrecCompare(2)` and `FixPrecCompare(3)` at the same time. So even if you make this compile, it will work as a global variable containing the last value you assigned to it, which is not a good thing to have anyways. I see 2 solutions here: either make everything a template parameter or use type erasure provided by `std::function`.

1. Works starting with C++20, as we need `double` template parameters here:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef bool(*SuccessTester)(double, double);

template<int numDigits>
struct FixPrecCompare
{
    static bool compare(double a, double b) { return int(a * factor) == int(b * factor); }
private:
    static constexpr double factor = pow(10, numDigits);
};

template<double abs_tol, double rel_tol>
struct AreClose
{
    static bool compare(double a, double b)
    {
        double diff = fabs(a - b);
        return diff <= abs_tol ||
            diff <= fabs(rel_tol * a) ||
            diff <= fabs(rel_tol * b);
    }
};

template<typename Functor>
SuccessTester makeSuccessTester()
{
    return &Functor::compare;
}

int main()
{
    SuccessTester fp;
    cout << boolalpha;

    double a, b;
    
    a = 4.561; b = 4.569;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare<2>>();
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 2 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare<3>>();
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 3 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    
    a = 2.7099; b = 2.7101;
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 3 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<AreClose<1e-3, 1e-10>>();
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " using areClose: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
}
```

2. 

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

using SuccessTester = std::function<bool(double, double)>;

struct FixPrecCompare
{
    FixPrecCompare(int numDigits): factor(pow(10, numDigits)) {}
    bool operator()(double a, double b) { return int(a * factor) == int(b * factor); }
private:
    double factor;
};

struct AreClose
{
    AreClose(double absTol, double relTol): abs_tol{absTol}, rel_tol{relTol} {}
    bool operator()(double a, double b)
    {
        double diff = fabs(a - b);
        return diff <= abs_tol ||
            diff <= fabs(rel_tol * a) ||
            diff <= fabs(rel_tol * b);
    }
private:
    double abs_tol, rel_tol;
};

template<typename Functor, typename ... ArgTypes>
SuccessTester makeSuccessTester(ArgTypes ... args)
{
    return Functor{args ...};
}

int main()
{
    SuccessTester fp;
    cout << boolalpha;

    double a, b;
    
    a = 4.561; b = 4.569;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare>(2);
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 2 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<FixPrecCompare>(3);
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 3 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    
    a = 2.7099; b = 2.7101;
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " to 3 decimals: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
    fp = makeSuccessTester<AreClose>(1e-3, 1e-10);
    cout << "Compare " << a << ", " << b << " using areClose: " << fp(a, b) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but 1) this is C++20, 2) normally functors aren't written this way right? Is there a way to just add the args also (not just their types) to the template `makeSuccessTester` so as to disambiguate but not change the constructor signature of the functor?

Comment: For disambiguation I was successful in passing __COUNTER__ as a dummy extra template parameter to Helper via a macro.

Comment: I'm not sure what precisely you mean by a functor, but if you want a wrapper for a callable object with value sematics, the most simple and natural thing to do is to use `std::function`. It is std, you know. And it is roughly equivalent to your Python example. The only caveat is performance, because `std::function` adds a level of indirection, it is a kind of runtime polymorphism.

Comment: If you are concerned with performance and you need compile-time polymorphism, then all depends on your requirements. You may just paramertize all corresponding classes and functions with a template parameter `SuccessTester` and pass around any object you need leaving the compiler an opportunity to inline it or whatever, as it is done in std algorithms. As to the `Helper` class, it looks like an extra entity to me, and I'm not sure what trick with a COUNTER may help here.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making it a macro:

```cpp
#define MAKE_SUCCESS_TESTER(F, ...)\
+[] (double x, double y) { \
auto fr = F{__VA_ARGS__}; \
return fr(x,y); \
}
```

It operates on the principle of creating a local, non-capturing lambda. These are implicitly convertible to function pointers.
The unary+ is not mandatory, but acts as a shorthand for `static_cast<SuccessTester>(/*lambda goes here*/);` enabling usage of type deduction when initializing the pointer and allowing somewhat better error diagnostic if capturing lambda is used accidentally:
Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889029/4885321).

```cpp
auto fp1 = MAKE_SUCCESS_TESTER_NO_PLUS_CAPTURING(FixPrecCompare, 2);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fp1), SuccessTester>);
```

I has the following **drawbacks**:

1. Type safety is gone. It's a macro; we could possibly fiddle with some static_asserts or similar inside the lambda, but fundamentally we're on our own here.
2. Passing immediate arguments might becomed complicated. It's fine for doubles, but trying to pass some initializer list there might result in an ugly compilation error. Again, typical for macros, but it's good to be aware of it.
3. It creates the inner `fr` object each time it's called. `auto fr = F{__VA_ARGS__};` can be made `static`, but then it would involve thread safe initialization, possibly a mutex being locked. Moreover, using this macro with the same parameters in a different translation unit will create a new lambda with a new static comparator inside. This is not necessarily bad, but it is something to be aware of.

If this still appeals to you, here is an example:
[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GWrWcfWdv).